# CORS request fail - PHP - GoDaddy shared hosting with URL forwarding

Tags: cors

I developed a game on my website that I am now converting to an app using Phonegap Build.  Phonegap Build requires that I pull the code from a GIT repository, which is working, but that also means I am now editing and testing my file on my (local) computer using Firefox.

My code has this AJAX call to a PHP file on my website:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "mysite.com/loadlocchars.php",
data: 'locid='+locid,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data)
{
$.each(data, function(key,i)
{
 // do stuff
});

}
});
```

I am still getting this CORS error, even though I added

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

as the first line in my PHP file  as instructed by this website:

http://enable-cors.org/server_php.html

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at mysite.com/loadlocchars.php. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

The domain name does a URL forward to my GoDaddy shared hosting, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.  I would rather not use JSONP as recommended in other SO answers.

Am I missing something?

Comment: hi @naoru just upload and compile with phonegap build.  it doesnt work when i run script on my local computer but worked when script was compiled and installed using PhoneGap Build on both my iOS and Android devices.  Why it doesnt work from a local computer is another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved!  GoDaddy shared hosting, domain forwarding, and even adding the CORS Access-Control statement at the beginning of my PHP file had nothing to do with it.

It wasn't working on my browser running the local file on my computer, but when I compiled with PhoneGap build and installed to my iOS and Android devices the script worked perfectly!  I did in fact try it without any CORS/PHP statements and it worked off the bat.

I am now curious as to why my files dont work when I run them on my local computer, but I suppose that is a seperate S/O question altogether, and one I will ask at a later time.  :-)

Comment: Have you came with any idea why the it doesn't work when running from the local computer? @Edward

Comment: Can you answer my question on this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51462377/can-i-use-shared-hosting-with-azure-with-amazon

Answer (score 2):

The response earlier helped me, but did not answer the question.

I figured this out. Had the SAME EXACT problem.

Yes it works in phonegap, but locally the Godaddy Shared hosting rejects the call.

To make it work with GoDaddy do this:

**Step 1:** Remove this code from your PHP files:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

**Step 2:** Place this code in your .htaccess file

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" //opens to any server
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost //opens for just localhost
```

Now you're good to go.