# Can I use Shared Hosting with Azure with Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, azure-table-storage, azure-files

Is it possible to use shared hosting with a web hosting provider along with Images on Amazon S3 Cloud provider?

Is it also possible to have a shared hosting with a web hosting provider along with Azure Blob/Azure Table storage?

The benefit is the low cost that I need to pay

Will Cross site origin policy be an issue?

Comment: Is it possible to provide an actual scenario, for example, are you trying to host a site, and host the content in multiple storage vendors Azure and AWS ?

Comment: I have a shared hosting site. Can I have azure code written in the mvc application on hosting? The app has azure dll right? So it can access the azure table storage as there is a connection string for azure